# How I can test api passport Laravel with postman (500 internal server error)

Tags: postman, laravel-passport

[image]

I am getting this error when I followed a tutorial. I check also in web for solution but I cannot find something...What I should do so I can work the test?

I receive class error when I have Facades....

[image]

Thanks to everybody anticipated!

Answer (score 0):

You miss spelled illuminate it should be Illuminate

Comment: Yes I fixed but still problem